# How to request GET method in specific url using Postman?

Tags: python, api, rest, request, postman

I want to get some results using Postman.

expected result :

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "message": "success",
    "results": {
        "count": "6816",
        "data": [
            {
                "timestamp": "2022-07-17T10:47:03Z",
                "sender": "0x2F664960a7FBdaDA8e133DbAF1Bfc27DCCBADBfb",
                "receiver": "0xA68A135Ccd37E720000fC30CFcc453b15F8040df",
                "value": "0",
                "status": "1",
                "message": "",
                "transaction_hash": "0x1a03528eecf165678d7fbcb9ceeee45a98b02f10a5ce30236ef29ee5b3747c84",
                "block_number": "2472",
                "contract_address": null,
                "trace_address": [
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "1"
                ],
                "trace_type": "staticcall",
                "sub_traces": null,
                "transaction_index": "0",
                "gas_used": "2715",
                "gas_limit": "29039032",
                "external_receiver": "0",
                "input": "0x0d2020dd476f7665726e616e6365436f6e74726163740000000000000000000000000000"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

When I request GET Method for example,

> API Docs : https://docs.wemix.com/v/en/dapp-developer/api-reference/account-apis#get-internal-transactions-by-address-and-get-internal-transactions-by-transaction-hash

> GET https://explorerapi.test.wemix.com/v1/accounts/0xA68A135Ccd37E720000fC30CFcc453b15F8040df/internal-transactions
> api-key: 1ba5e446edf1997f67b51bf9e60b3fbba6fa1bf84301115292805d7e24f43539RESPONSE DATA

I requests GET method using 'api-key' using Postman

but, my response is,

```
{
    "status": "401",
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

How to fix it to get proper response?
Or, is there a good way to call API with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Khalil's answer - to do the same in python you could do the following:

```
import requests

headers = {'api-key': '1ba5e446edf1997f67b51bf9e60b3fbba6fa1bf84301115292805d7e24f43539'}
response = requests.get('https://explorerapi.test.wemix.com/v1/accounts/0xA68A135Ccd37E720000fC30CFcc453b15F8040df/internal-transactions', headers=headers)
print(response)
```

<Response [200]> which will get you the data that you desire.

The API Key that was provided had `RESPONSE DATA` at the end which was invalid as the API key.

Comment: Thanks, May I ask one more question? In API docs, they refers query-string 'offset' meaning "Start retrieve record". I confuse to understand that meaning cause i'm Korean. Can you tell me what does that exact meaning?

Comment: I'm not completely sure as I don't use that API. However, it seems to mean the difference between where it would normally start and the `offset` int to retrieve records. Such as a list the start could instead of being at 0 be at a different offset int.

Answer (score 1):

On the `Headers` tab, you need to add a key `api-key` with the api key `1ba5e446edf1997f67b51bf9e60b3fbba6fa1bf84301115292805d7e24f43539` in the value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, May I ask one more question?
In API docs, they refers query-string 'offset' meaning "Start retrieve record".
I confuse to understand that meaning cause i'm Korean.
Can you tell me what does that exact meaning?

Comment: offset basically means to retrieve results from a specified position. For example, an API returns the names of students. An offset of 5, would mean returning the names starting from the 6th position of the list consisting of student names.